# Are template template template parameters an extension or part of the standard?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I was searching for something else related to template template parameters and happened upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485439) which claims that template template template parameters are *not* allowed by the standard.

However, the following code compiles in the latest clang (3.2) and the latest GCC (4.8):

```cpp
template<template<template<typename> class> class T> struct test {};
template<template<typename> class T> struct foo {};
test<foo> bar;
```

Is this an extension, or is the other answer actually incorrect and it is allowed by the standard? If not, is there any particular reason for the omission?

Comment: @chris OP probably means a snapshot of 4.8. I have been using one for a while.

Comment: Yeah, I have snapshots from MacPorts... so, probably not the latest svn or anything like that.

Comment: it also compiles on gcc 4.5 on Ideone http://ideone.com/BUAuw

Comment: Oh, yeah, the code as I posted it does fail to link since there's no main().

Comment: MSVC 2010 also compiles this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `std::vector<int>` the class template `std::vector` is passed the type `int` as a parameter. In `std::get<42>(some_tuple)`, the function template `std::get` is passed the value `42` as a parameter. Perhaps unimaginatively the former kind of argument is called a type argument of a template (or template type argument) while the latter kind is a (template) non-type argument.

But templates can also accept another kind of arguments: other templates. For instance `template<template<typename> class T> void foo();` declares a function template taking a template as argument, that itself takes a type argument. (As a note, while templates are not types the term 'non-type argument' still does not cover template template arguments. It is reserved for arguments like `template<int NonTypeArgument>`.)

Since there is no such thing as a template template in C++ (there are class, function, and alias templates -- but they're collectively simply 'templates' anyway), there is no such thing as a template template template parameter. What you have is a run off the mill template template parameter, where the expected template argument has a template template argument itself. I cannot find a reference in the Standard that forbids this, like the answer you link claims.