# How to use a type with template as a template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm trying to use different types of containers of different types with the same function but couldn't convince my compiler. Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

// error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
template<typename C<T>>
void func1() {
  C<T> c;
  c.push_back(new T);
}

// error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
template<typename C<typename T>>
void func2() {
  C<T> c;
  c.push_back(new T);
}

// error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
template<typename C<template <typename T>>>
void func3() {
  C<T> c;
  c.push_back(new T);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  func1<vector<int>>();
  func1<list<float>>();

  func2<vector<int>>();
  func2<list<float>>();

  func3<vector<int>>();
  func3<list<float>>();
  return 0;
}
```

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: Looks like you just want `typename T`.

Comment: @chris what do you mean? I need both the container type (e.g `vector`) and the underlying type (e.g. `int`) in my application.

Comment: You're passing in instantiations, not the class template itself (e.g., `func1<vector>()`. The function could then just be `T t(1);` to have the same effect. Keep in mind not all containers support the same operations.

Comment: @chris can you write an example as an answer? I'm not sure I get what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I think you can get to your original code (assuming you wanted two parameters, `C` and `T` and not just one `C<T>`) is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template<template< class T, class A = allocator<T> > class C, typename T>
void func() {
  C<T*> c;
  c.push_back(new T);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  func<vector, int>();
  func<list, float>();
  return 0;
}
```

Notice two things:

1. The `vector` and `list` templates take two parameters, the second one defaulting to `allocator<T>` (where `T` is the first parameter).  You cannot define the template with just one parameter; the type system will complain when instantiating.
2. If you have a container of type `C<T>` with a `push_back` method expecting a `T` (like `vector` and `list`), you cannot pass it `new T` as a parameter.  I took the liberty of fixing the container to be of type `C<T*>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about ***"template template parameters"***.

Template-template parameters are a kind of type template parameters which template classes are allowed only. That class template could have any kind of template parameters. For example:

```
template<template<typename T , typename ALLOCATOR> class CONTAINER>
void func2()
{
    CONTAINER<T,ALLOCATOR> container;

    container.push_back( T() );
} 

int main()
{
    func2<std::vector<bool>>();
}
```

This is useful when you need to extract the template parameters of a class template which you have passed as template parameter.
Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484484/template-template-parameters) for more info.

On the other hand, as chris noticed in his answer, in your case its easier to pass a type parameter and suppose that type has a member type `value_type`, which is used to get the type of the elements of the container.

Comment: I feel like this is what I was looking for but it doesn't compile on my machine, says `error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'`. Also do I need an `ALLOCATOR` parameter or that's just an example?

Answer (score 2):

From your calls, I suspect you just want something like this (I'll make the code as close to what you have as possible and keep it C++03):

```
template<typename T>
void func1() {
    T t;
    t.push_back(typename T::value_type());
}
```

`typename` expects a type - any type - and that's what it gets with `vector<int>`, `list<float>`, etc. On the other hand, `vector` by itself is just a template, not a type on its own. That's when you would need `template<template<...> class>` syntax.

Do note, however, that trying to group containers like this often won't work because not every container supports the same operations as others. If you need an interface like this, you'll have to differentiate sequence containers, associative containers, etc.

Comment: I was planning to wrap these STL containers so they would have the same interface which also means I need a field called `value_type` on my custom classes, am I right?

Comment: @gokcehan, You would, among other things (listed as container requirements in the standard). You will, at some level, have to differentiate between the different kinds of containers, though.

Answer (score 1):

first of all `new` will return a pointer, so the containers will not accept this, change that line, also you could do the following:

```
template<typename Container, typename T >
void func1() {
  Container c;
  c.push_back(T());
}
```

and in the main function:

```
func1<std::vector<int>, int >();
```

Comment: I like this solution. There is just a little bit redundancy in `func1<vector<int>, int>` but that's not quite an annoyance.