# template< template <typename> something_else >, what is this?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I'm just starting learning C++11 and I never saw this syntax in the list of new features:

```
template <template <typename> class F>
struct fun;
```

what is it and how does it work?

Comment: You may also want to read the tag wiki of *template template-parameters*: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/template-templates/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** What you are looking at is an "old" feature, and has been there since long before c++11.</sup>

---

```
template <template <typename> class F> struct Obj;
```

In the above `Obj` is a template only accepting a template-parameter which is also a template<sup>[1]</sup>; this is most often referred to as a [*template-template parameter*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485439/1090079) <sup>[2]</sup>.

<sup><sup>1)</sup> in this specific example it will only accept a template that takes one type-parameter.
<sup>2)</sup> Link to SO question: [Template Template Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485439/1090079)</sup>

---

Imagine that you'd like to have a wrapper around some class template; you don't care which class template this is as long as you can specify a template argument for it.

If so, you can use a *template-template parameter* as in the below example:

```
template<template<typename T> class TemplateType>
struct Obj {
  TemplateType<  int> m1;
  TemplateType<float> m2;
};
```

```
template<typename T>
struct SomeTemplate { /* ... */  };

Obj<SomeTemplate> foo;
```

---

In the above, `foo` will be a `Obj<SomeTemplate>` having two members:

1. `SomeTemplate<  int> m1`
2. `SomeTemplate<float> m2`

Comment: and can I use it without any "T"? e.g. template<template<typename> class MemberTemplateType> struct Obj .. ?

Comment: @user3425677 the names inside the *template-template parameter* doesn't matter, declaring it without naming `T` has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

This should works in C++98 as well. This is a template as an argument from a template. I mean a template class will expected as the argument for F.
Maybe this page will help you: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html