# in template<template<class> class T1, class T2>, what is the meaning of <class>?

Tags: c++, templates

I found some example of template in Modern C++ Design by A. Alexenderscu
where author used following lines

```
template
<
class T,
template <class> class CheckingPolicy  // <---- Please explain this line
>
class SmartPtr : public CheckingPolicy<T>
{
...
template
<
class T1,
template <class> class CP1,
>
SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T1, CP1>& other)
    : pointee_(other.pointee_), CheckingPolicy<T>(other)
{ ... }
};
```

i do not understand meaning of  in marked line. Please explain that line

Comment: It is a template template parameter. `<class>` means that it has one type parameter.

Comment: can you explain it more ... what one type parameter. Mean same type as type as class T ( declared above )

Comment: In this code example `SmartPtr` class template has one type parameter `T` and one template parameter `CheckingPolicy`. `CheckingPolicy` template template parameter itself has one type parameter: `template <class> class CheckingPolicy`.

Comment: @Constructor That should be an answer.

Comment: @Angew Do you mean I should post it as an answer?

Comment: @Constructor Yes. There's no point in answering a question in comments, in fact it's actively discouraged. It only makes sense if writing a proper answer would take significantly more time than a simple comment, and you happen not to have that time. But here, the answer does not require much beyond what you put in the two comments already.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484484/template-template-parameters please

Comment: @Angew Thank you for your explanation. I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code example `SmartPtr` class template has one type parameter `T` and one template parameter `CheckingPolicy`. `CheckingPolicy` template template parameter itself has one type parameter: `template <class> class CheckingPolicy`. I recommend you to format template code which is unclear for you in the following way to make it more understandable:

```
template
    <
        class T, // type parameter of a SmartPtr class template
        template
            <
                class // type parameter of a template parameter CheckingPolicy
            >
        class CheckingPolicy // template parameter of a SmartPtr class template
    >
class SmartPtr // class template
```

Comment: Simply put, the name of the template is ignored in `template<class>` instead of `template<class Foo>`. Similar to functions `void foo(int)` instead of `void foo(int bar)`

Comment: @balki Thank you for your valuable remark. But there are some cases in which it would not be ignored.