# How can I write a template function that takes a generic C++ standard library container

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a function that needs to be able to work for different container types, for example

```
void foo(const std::vector<bar>& param1, const std::vector<double>& params2)
```

and

```
void foo(const std::list<bar>& param1, const std::list<double>& params2)
```

where `bar` is a `class` that I've written. The function body itself uses generic C++ standard library functions.

Is there a way I can templatise this? I have tried

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T<bar>&, const T<double>&)
```

But this gives the compiler error

> error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

I'm using MSVC2015.

Comment: The "C++ way" of passing containers to template functions is: don't; pass iterators instead.

Comment: I've added a return type to match the answer,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare `T` as [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) to indicate that it's a template-name (and needs arguments to be instantiated), e.g.

```
template<template <typename...> class T> 
void foo(const T<bar>&, const T<double>&);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/DLB33632)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately on my compiler I get "template parameter T is ambiguous", could be std::_List_buy or std::list.

Comment: MSVC issue due to their chucking so much stuff into `std::`? Hack the call site with `foo<std::list>(`

Answer (score 4):

There are basically three solutions:

1. Use [template template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484484/template-template-parameters).
2. Use iterators (which is what the standard library itself uses)
3. Use different templates for different arguments, and let the compiler deduce the actual types. With your function it would be something like

   ```
   template<typename T, typename U> void foo(const T&, const U&);
   ```

Solution 2 is the recommended one if you just need to iterate over the contents of the container. Solution 3 is the recommended one if you need access tot he container itself.

Comment: 2) and 3) would also allow to use foo with `std::array`s, while in case of 1) one would need to create additional overload

Comment: @W.F. Solution 2 works with *any* container (even plain arrays or dynamically allocated memory). Solution 3 works with any container that works with the member-functions called.

Answer (score 0):

So-called template template arguments will allow you to write the desired code (as also shown in other answers or over on [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)).

Alternatively, you could also write generic functions that accept [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). This is exactly how the functions in the `<algorithm>` are implemented. I tend to believe that functions that accept iterators are actually more flexible as the caller can decide what range needs to be processed by the function.