# How to extract the types passed in template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameters, template-classes

In the below code, I want to replace "something" with something that will allow me to declare the type of 'f' as the second parameter passed in C (while passing C to M's template), i.e., float here.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class A, class B>
class C{
    public :
        A a;
        B b;
};
template<class D>
class M{
    public :
        decltype(D::<something>) f;  //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        void show(){cout<<f;}
};
int main(){
    M<C<int,float>> m;
    m.show();
}
```

Comment: Is `decltype(D::b)` good enough for you?

Comment: No, without seeing that. Without looking into the definition of class C. @Quentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a template taking a template?

With the following line you can declare a template taking a template and have the latter's template arguments types named:

```
template<
template<typename, typename> class D, 
          typename A, typename B>
```

With this notation you are saying that D is a is a template parameter which is itself in turn a template and `A` and `B` are the types that it takes.
Now you can refer to the first and second template parameter of D with the names `A` and `B`.

---

```
using namespace std;
template<class A, class B>
class C{
    public :
        A a;
        B b;
};
template<template<typename, typename> class T, typename A, typename B>
class M{
    public :
        B f;  //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        void show(){cout<<f;}
};
int main(){
    M<C, int, float> m;
    m.show();
}
```

For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484484/template-template-parameters) answer out.

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening in the line template< template<typename,typename> class T,typename A, typename B>

Comment: And why you don't have to write M<C<int,float>,int,float>?

Comment: You do not write `C<int,float>` because `M` first template parameter is now a template and not a class. Remember that `C` is a template but `C<int,float>` is not a template anymore. it is a fully-fledged class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with some trickery.

```
template<typename> class M; // leave undefined
template<template<typename, typename> D, 
         typename One,
         typename Two>
 class M<D<One, Two>> { // a specialisation
     Two f;
 };
```

Now you can pass to `M` a class that has exactly two template parameters (sich as `C<int, float>`). If you pass something else (e.g. `int`) there will be an error.