# Double template argument for a template function

Tags: c++, templates

What would be a valid definition of this function to be called in *main* as the following?

```
foo<float, double>(sqrtfunction< float>, floatList);
```

I was wondering if it’s done with template classes, but isn't possible to do this without calling it as a member of a class?

*foo* is a function which calls sqrtfunction which applies the sqrtfunction to every element in the "floatList" and returns the list in type of float in this case (type of the sqrtfunction).
Whereas the output of *foo* is saved in a vector instance of type *double*.

Comment: Please make more detail about your question, what is foo? and what is foo2?

Comment: You don't need to pass `sqrtfunction()` in parameters if `foo` is supposed to call only this function and no other one. You need to pass a function in parameters when it's meant to be substitutable with any function matching the prototype.

Comment: I don't understand the need for templates here too.

Comment: Are you want something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/69468279/1539100 answer? or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [user *463035818*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467461/double-template-argument-for-template-function/69468033#69468033) resolved your problem.

But if you want to write a template function, you can write something like this:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
T my_sqrt(T value)
{
        return std::sqrt(value);
}

template <typename I, typename ElementType>
auto sqrt_function(std::function<I(I)> sqrt_func, const std::vector<I>& elements) -> std::vector<ElementType>
{
        std::vector<ElementType> results;
        std::transform(elements.cbegin(), elements.cend(), std::back_inserter(results), sqrt_func);

        return results;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> results = sqrt_function<float, double>(my_sqrt<float>, std::vector<float>(10, 9.f));
    std::copy(results.cbegin(), results.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

And if you want to use [template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6484484/1539100) you can modify above code like below

```cpp
template <typename I, template<typename> class List, typename ElementType>
auto sqrt_function(std::function<I(I)> sqrt_func, const List<I>& elements) -> std::vector<ElementType>
{
        std::vector<ElementType> results;
        std::transform(elements.cbegin(), elements.cend(), std::back_inserter(results), sqrt_func);

        return results;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> results = sqrt_function<float, std::vector, double>(my_sqrt<float>, std::vector<float>(10, 9.f));
    std::copy(results.cbegin(), results.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> x{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<double> y(x.size());
    auto sqrt = [](double x){ return std::sqrt(x);};
    std::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),sqrt);
    for (const auto& elem : y) std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/44G6hrW8K):

```
1 1.41421 1.73205 2 2.23607
```

Generally, `std::transform` works with any unary operation that transforms one element to another and assigns the transformed elements to the range starting at `y.begin()`. The conversion from `float` to `double` takes place when the algorithm passes elements of `x` to the lambda (and because it calls `double std::sqrt(double)`, the result is `double`).